# $PATH variable for CRON in OpenSuse

Tags: linux, cron, opensuse, path

I have a script written which works perfect on terminal however gives error when called through crontab. It took me a while that the problem is with the cron environment not my script.

so I tried few options after reading various posts online:

`* * * * * PATH=/home/sam/bin:/home/sam/scriptbin/ /path/to/script`
           Didn't work

`* * * * * bash -lc /path/to/script` Didn't work

`* * * * * /path/to/script` Didn't work

```
`PATH=blahdeblah
* * * * * jobdejob` Didn't work
```

How can I change `$PATH` variable for crontab in OPENSUSE or include in cron file so that it works. I am using open suse 11.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two ways; first, some cron daemons allow environment variables to be set:

```
PATH=blahdeblah
* * * * * jobdejob
```

Second, use the `env(1)` utility, which then runs the actual job:

```
* * * * * env PATH=blahdeblah jobdejob
```

Three! Use fully qualified paths in the cron jobs. No, no, four ways, as Jeff says, set the path in the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=blahdeblah
...
```

Fifth, a ruthless devotion to the `PATH`.

Comment: can you share more on env(1).. no idea what is that?

Comment: Or for better locality, set the PATH you need at the top of your script.

Comment: I second @JeffSchaller's idea instead of making life harder for yourself, trying to figure out how your cron daemon will react

Comment: neither of the above two options seems to work..